# Rails: What security vulnerabilities are there when storing Facebook id and secret inside an initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, git

I have read that when storing the app_id and app_secret, you do not want to directly add them to the code in your initializer. That there are security vulnerabilities. Solutions like Heroku allow you to create env variables for something like this, but I want to understand what the vulnerabilities really are.

If these keys were written within my initializer code, committed to git, and pushed to a private repo on github, and deployed using Heroku. What security vulnerabilities exist?

Answer (score 0):

The first concern we, as developers, think when securing our app is some hacker from the outside world being able to get data that it should not be able to get direct from our app. We should then get our app rock solid, right?

Well, even that being nearly impossible, there are at least two more ways besides a direct vulnerability on your app:

1. **Social engineering**
2. **Enterprise network vulnerability**

**Social engineering**: Must be the most hard leak to close, people ability to detect they are being taking into it will vary over time, and will depend in a lot of things(mood, money, ...). [You're just a phone call from leaking information](http://www.cnet.com/news/social-engineering-101-mitnick-and-other-hackers-show-how-its-done/)

**Enterprise network vulnerability**: The chain is as safe as its weakest link. If you make your app the unique 100% unbreakable in the know world, some still can be able to use an open door on your company network to get credentials from your app. This method is often used with social engineering, first gaining access to the intranet to proceed to your application.

To mitigate those vulnerabilities you should close as much as possible the access to your credentials, to the point that even you can't get them easy.

Adding production credentials into the repository will lead to more people  being able to see it and easier to a hacker get access to it(even just sniffing your wifi network).

Putting your credentials into env vars will not be a perfect solution, but at least you will decrease the amount of people with access to it(#1) and it will transit a lot less(#2).

There is no way to being 100% secure, but you should work hard to make it as close as you can to mitigate possible flaws.